# How do I view the XML structure of Magento?

Tags: xml, overrides, debugging, simplexml

As I understand, Magento meshes the layout and config xml into a Simplexml object. Does anyone know where this object gets stored? I want to view the entire xml of Magento so I can find any model rewrites in the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is stored in a not-human readable format in `var/cache` from the caching (if activated) if caching is not active it only lives in memory.

If you want to see it, I think you can do the following in the end of `index.php`:

```
echo Mage::app()->getConfig()->getXmlString(); // for the merged config
// and
echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->getXmlString(); // for the merged layout
```

Comment: Didn't show when placed at the end of index.php, but I had a adminhtml controller I occasionally use for debugging, this worked in there. But it isn't structured really. So I just did `echo "<pre>";print_r(Mage::app()->getConfig());`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!